# vb script to extract the executable jar file response

Tags: vbscript, executable-jar, hp-uft

I have a scenario to execute a executable jar file and then need to capture the response from the command prompt.

```
Option Explicit
    Dim StrCmd,Path,processFile,str
    Path = "D:\modulefolder" 
    processFile = "java -jar xxx.jar"
    StrCmd = "CD /D "& Path & " & " & processFile &""
    Call Run(StrCmd,1,False)
    Function Run(StrCmd,Console,bWaitOnReturn)
        Dim ws,MyCmd,Result, str1

        Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    'A value of 0 to hide the MS-DOS console
        If Console = 0 Then
            MyCmd = "CMD /K " & StrCmd & ""
            Result = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,bWaitOnReturn)
    *some code using sendkeys to type in command prompt****
```

Can somebody please tell me how should I extract the response code from command prompt at the end..

e.g. I get Response code 201 for pass & 400 or 405 for failure scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the output of `stdout` and `stderr` to a text file and read that:

```
java -jar myApp.jar >file.txt 2>&1
```

This will redirect the output from the jar file into `file.txt`, which you can read using a `FileSystemObject`

```
Dim Fso : Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim File : Set File = Fso.OpenTextFile("Path/to/file.txt", 1)
Dim Text : Text = File.ReadAll
```

`Text` now contains the content of the file as a variable for you to use as required.